# How to convert midi type 1 files to midi type 0 in Python or Command-line?

Tags: python, command-line, midi

I am trying to convert a midi file of type 1 to type 0.  Is there a Python library that can do it? Or alternatively is there some code that can be run from the command-line that could do the conversion?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I convert a Standard MIDI File from Type 1 to Type 0?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/39040/how-can-i-convert-a-standard-midi-file-from-type-1-to-type-0)

Comment: The linked question doesn't specify the solution should be in Python

Comment: Duplicate link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Mido (`pip install mido`) converts from type 1 to type 0:

```
import mido

m = mido.MidiFile('solstice.mid')
mido.merge_tracks(m.tracks)
```

Answer (score 0):

The midi file in type 0 has one track only. Just split channels into multi tracks and recalculate the time if type 0 to type 1.

Convert midi type 1 to type 0, you can join tracks into one with multi channels and recalculate the time.

type 0 to type 1 Code here: https://gist.github.com/weibangtuo/6a5a60a7984247548ad685d77fbd9f58